# SharePoint is throwing access denied when url changes from http://site to http://www.site

Tags: windows, sharepoint-2007, iis-6, windows-server-2003

We have a SharePoint 2007 site which has FBA configured (extended the webapp to different zone). The problem is that a user has to authenticate twice when the URL changes from http://site to http://www.site i.e if the user enters http://site it asks for username and after authenticating if the user clicks on a url containg http://www.site it authenticates again.

Our host header has both enteries for http and http://www.

Can anyone help me fix this issue (why is SharePoint treating http:// and http://www differently).

Comment: I think this is a serverfault question...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a SharePoint problem.  The reason this is occuring is the FBA auth cookie is being set for `http://site` as the domain, so when the user navigates to `http://www.site`, the cookie isn't getting passed back to the server, and the user is being seen as unauthenticated.

I don't think there is a way to set the cookie for both sites without writing some code (if its even possible).